# Laravel 5.4: Filter and meet all arguments from request

Tags: laravel-5, collections, request, product

I need your help. Still learning a lot about Laravel and been searching the whole web for a solid answer to this question. I'm trying to get a collection of products that meet all the given request arguments. So:

```
?brand=adidas,nike&gender=women
```

Will get me all the Adidas & Nike shoes for Women.

I've got this so far:

```
$brandRequest = $request->brand;
$brandReqArray = explode(',', $brandRequest);

$genderRequest = $request->gender;
$genderReqArray = explode(',', $genderRequest);

$products = Product::with('brands', 'genders')
->whereHas('brands', function($query) use ($brandReqArray)  {
    $query->whereIn('slug', $brandReqArray);
})
->orWhereHas('genders', function($query) use ($genderReqArray)  {
    $query->whereIn('slug', $genderReqArray);
})->paginate(24);
```

I'm getting all the Adidas & Nike shoes and I'm getting all the women shoes. But if I'm trying both it shows nothing.

Here's my table structure: [DB Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbIRe.png)

Can someone point me in the right direction or maybe even has a solution for this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should consider using `->when` in your laravel query to make conditional statement. , Please note that you cannot use inbuilt pagination in this way, it will not work appropriately, because pagination link is constructed without taking care of your parameters exist in the URL, I would advice you to make an ajax pagination.

try to execute this query and it should work without pagination.

```
$products = Product::when($request->has('brand'), function ($query)use($request) {
        $brandRequest = $request->input('brand');
        $brandReqArray = explode(',', $brandRequest);

        $query->whereHas('brands', function($q) use ($brandReqArray)  {
            $q->whereIn('slug', $brandReqArray);
        });
    })->when($request->has('gender'), function ($query)use($request) {
        $genderRequest = $request->input('gender');
        $genderReqArray = explode(',', $genderRequest);

        $query->whereHas('genders', function($q) use ($genderReqArray)  {
            $q->whereIn('slug', $genderReqArray);
        });
    })->get();
```

for pagination, please try this way, but I advice you to avoid constructing pagination from URL parameter for security concerns,

```
$products = Product::when($request->filled('brand'), function ($query)use($request) {
        $brandRequest = $request->input('brand');
        $brandReqArray = explode(',', $brandRequest);

        $query->whereHas('brands', function($q) use ($brandReqArray)  {
            $q->whereIn('slug', $brandReqArray);
        });
    })->when($request->filled('gender'), function ($query)use($request) {
        $genderRequest = $request->input('gender');
        $genderReqArray = explode(',', $genderRequest);

        $query->whereHas('genders', function($q) use ($genderReqArray)  {
            $q->whereIn('slug', $genderReqArray);
        });
    })->paginate(10);
    $input = $request->only(['brands', 'gender']);
    $products->appends($input);
```

come to my blog and write any Laravel help OR find existing solution which might be helpful for you,
https://www.techalyst.com/

for ajax pagination refer one of my old article.
https://www.techalyst.com/links/read/97/laravel-ajax-pagination-for-collection-query-builder-complex-sql-query-result

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer some more? I'm trying this now but keep getting the same result. How would you apply this to my given code?

Comment: what I understood is you want to filter all products by brand and gender, and you want it conditionally when it present in URL request data?, 
if i am correct can you please add your table structure to understand it first,

Comment: check, I have updated my answer, and if you are using Laravel 5.5 or 5.6, you have to replace `$request->has()` with `$request->filled()` as in the second example.